# I want get the sum of integers?

Tags: python

I am a beginner and I wrote this code, but how can I make it output the sum of the integers?

```
a=100
b=200
for a in range (b):
    if a%2==1:
       print a
```

Comment: do you mean the sum of `a` and `b`?

Comment: No I mean the sum of the odd integers between 100 and 200

Comment: I don't see any attempt at summation whatsoever. SO is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you mean the sum of all the numbers `a < x < b`, then this will do it.

```
a = 100
b = 200
total = 0

for i in range(a,b+1):
    total += i

print total
```

In this case it will print `15150`.

As per your question, if you want just odd numbers:

```
for i in range(a, b+1):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        total += 1
```

I know this isn't a 1 liner approach to the solution, but I wrote it out in this manner so that you could understand it better and more clearly. Also because it looks like you were taking an approach like this, and I wanted you to see how it would be done the way that you were trying to do it.

Comment: what if I want just odd integers

Comment: @sola Updated my question to provide an implementation for that. It's super simple, just an `if` statement checking to see if it's odd.